# What formula in macro can I use to show a value as dd:hh:mm, exceeding 31 days?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros, format

When using the format for `dd:hh:mm` Excel gives us, it is not possible to show an amount of days greater than 31.

Using the following formula in macro is not possible

```
=INT(C5)&":"&TEXT(C5,"hh:mm:ss")
```

Does anyone know a way to translate a number to `dd:hh:mm` using a VBA macro?

Comment: Related (without really being relevant): [How do you format an Excel date to represent >31 days with hours, minutes and seconds?](https://superuser.com/q/893977/150988)

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure what it is you are after but I think what you were looking for is the [`Format`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) function?

```
Sub Test()

Dim C5As Double: C5= 44.509201
Debug.Print Int(C5) & ":" & Format(C5, "hh:mm")

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: @Den, has this been helpfull to answer your question?